# docker compose .env substitution not working within labels

Tags: docker, docker-compose, .env

I am trying to pass .env variables from two different .env files into my docker compose service.

The substitution of .env variables is described here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/.

The .env variable is correctly accessible via the shell inside the container but is not distributed to the labels.

I was expecting that the labels and variables in the shell have the same value.

I did this:

1. create 1.env without specific variable:

```
#FOO=bar
```

2. create 2.env with specific variable

```
FOO=bar
```

3. create docker-compose.yaml with link to .env: **traefik.http.routers.homarr.rule=Host(`${FOO}`)**

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  homarr:
    container_name: homarr
    image: ghcr.io/ajnart/homarr:latest
    env_file:
      - ./1.env
      - ./2.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # Optional, only if you want docker integration
      - ./configs:/app/data/configs
      - ./icons:/app/public/icons
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - "7575:7575"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.homarr.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.homarr.rule=Host(`${FOO}`)
      - traefik.http.services.homarr.loadbalancer.server.port=7575
```

4. Start service

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

5. check labels with docker inspect **traefik.http.routers.homarr.rule**

```json
"Labels": {
  "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "abfaf96d72de93ea9d00fea29091d243cc28e5e3b22b59008e022b3235f53ad1",
  "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
  "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
  "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:e9661b9c94221c66941b32d41714e629c62a48029e51888617290aa6004521fe",
  "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
  "com.docker.compose.project": "homarr",
  "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "D:\\dev\\webdev\\dockerExp\\homarr\\docker-compose.yaml",
  "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "D:\\dev\\webdev\\dockerExp\\homarr",
  "com.docker.compose.service": "homarr",
  "com.docker.compose.version": "2.23.3",
  "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2023-12-31T11:39:59.537Z",
  "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Customizable browser's home page to interact with your homeserver's Docker containers (e.g. Sonarr/Radarr)",
  "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "MIT",
  "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "b4a8d47636c5495a3312d5d72e3d14e7573fc7c8",
   "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/ajnart/homarr",
  "org.opencontainers.image.title": "homarr",
  "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/ajnart/homarr",
  "org.opencontainers.image.version": "0.14.3",
  "traefik.docker.network": "frontend",
  "traefik.enable": "true",
  "traefik.http.routers.homarr.entrypoints": "web",
  "traefik.http.routers.homarr.rule": "Host(``)",
  "traefik.http.services.homarr.loadbalancer.server.port": "7575"
}
```

6. go exec into container and run echo:

```bash
# echo $FOO
bar
#
```

Comment: From the [same documentation you linked](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#use-the-env_file-attribute) specifically in regards to `env_file`... _"Environment variables declared in the `.env` file **cannot** then be referenced again separately in the Compose file."_. You'll either need to use the `--env-file` CLI option